# .BLADE.PHP IS NOT WORKING IN MY LARAVEL PROJECT. .PHP IS WORKING FINE FOR MY VIEWS

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-blade

laravel .blade.php extension is not working. even when I try to keep my views inside other folders. that views are not getting called. when I make .php extension its working fine.but when i make it as .blade.php extension then it is not workin. throwing expception view not found. what could be the issue

Comment: you should give us more info of your code and views. 
Blase has several instructions to make it work.

Comment: please look below comment by which will show you code. I got this code online as blade template example. but it is not working. I am code Igniter developer. started working on laravel in last few weeks ago..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can suggest on the information you provided is: Make sure when you put your views inside other folders you use dot syntax and not slashes like this:

`View::make('folder.view');`

Instead of

`View::make('folder/view');`

Folder Structure:

```
|views|
--|folder|
----view.blade.php
```

Answer (score 0):

there are four files in views/include folder -head.blade.php,header.blade.php,footer.blade.php, sidebar.blade.php,  views/layouts folder contain index.blade.php code is

```
<html>
<head>
    @include('includes.head')
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <header class="row">
        @include('includes.header')
    </header>

    <div id="main" class="row">

            @yield('content')

    </div>

    <footer class="row">
        @include('includes.footer')
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then views/pages contain about.blade.php contains

```
@extends('layouts.index')
@section('content')
    i am the about page
@stop
```

and routes.php contain

```
Route::get('about', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.about');
});
```

any thing else needed please let me know. what is wrong with code, I dont understand,,,,

output is

@extends('layouts.index')
    @section('content')
        i am the about page
    @stop